# fabricjs: retain the correct indexes of an object's image filters after loadFromJSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, fabricjs, javascript-objects, fabricjs2

I am applying filters to objects (following [image filters demo](http://fabricjs.com/image-filters)) and everything is ok but after I save and load the canvas, the image filters change index.

At the moment I have four filters and they are applied by index (as shown in the demo).

> 0 : Grayscale
>
> 1 : Invert
>
> 2 : Remove Color
>
> 3 :- Blend Color

So if I apply Grayscale, and Remove Color, the 'filters' array looks like this , with indexes 0 and 2 which is correct...

[image]

But after I load the canvas (using loadFromJSON), the object's 'filters' array looks like this, with the indexes reset...

[image]

Is there any way that I can load the object and retain the filter indexes? There is code that is dependant on this and it is causing errors when I load a canvas that has objects with filters.

I have tried applying the following upon creation of the object...

```
   oImg.filters = [
     false,
     false,
     false,
     false
   ];;
```

It works ok when the object is created...

[image]

But when it is loaded, the false indexes are removed and its the same result...

[image]

Comment: I have managed to get this working by applying functions by type rather than by index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to get this working by changing the way I applied and retrieved the filters (by type rather than index). I simply checked to see if the filter existed (by 'type' not index), then spliced the filter at the desired index.

Changed this function...

```
getFilter(index) { 
   var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
   return obj.filters[index];
}
```

to this...

```
getFilter(type) { 
  var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
  if (obj) {
    filter = null;
    obj.filters.forEach(function(f) {
      if (f.type == type) {
        filter = f;
      }
    });
    return filter;
  }
}
```

---

Changed this function...

```
applyFilter(index, filter) {
  var object = canvas.getActiveObject();
  object.filters[index] = filter;
  object.applyFilters();
  canvas.renderAll();
}
```

to this...

```
applyFilter(type, filterIndex, filter) {
  var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
  var indexExists = false;
  var filterFound = false;

  if (obj) {
    obj.filters.forEach(function(f, i) {
      if (f.type == type) {
        filterFound = true;
        obj.filters[i] = filter;
      } 
      if (filterIndex == i) {
        indexExists = true;
      } 
    });

    if (!filterFound && indexExists) {
      obj.filters.splice(filterIndex, 0, filter);
    } else if (!filterFound && !indexExists) {
      obj.filters[filterIndex] = filter;
    }

  }
  obj.applyFilters();
  canvas.renderAll();
}
```

---

Changed this function...

```
applyFilterValue(index, prop, value) {
  var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
  if (obj.filters[index]) {
    obj.filters[index][prop] = value;
    obj.applyFilters();
    canvas.renderAll();
  }
}
```

to this...

```
applyFilterValue(type, filterIndex, prop, value) {
  var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
  if (obj) {
    obj.filters.forEach(function(f, i) {
      if (f.type == type) {
        obj.filters[i][prop] = value;
      }
    });
  }
  obj.applyFilters();
  canvas.renderAll();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my current project i need to have the ability to customize the order of the filters. The problem with lost indexing after `canvas.toDatalessJSON()` gave me the idea to make a simple solution for that.
I simply build a new array of filternames every time og load the canvas.

```
const filterNamesDefault = ['Contrast', 'Saturation', 'Sharpen', 'Tint', 'invert', 'grayscale', 'Sepia'];

var filterNames = [];
var canvasLoaded = false;
```

`canvasLoaded` is a boolean that has to be set to true when a canvas has been loaded.
Then in the `applyFilterType` and `applyFilterValue` functions i provide the functions with the filter type instead of the index:

```
function filterIndex(filterType) {
      if (canvasLoaded) { return filterNames.indexOf(filterType); } else { return filterNamesDefault.indexOf(filterType); } 
} 

function applyFilterType(type, filter) {
     var index=filterIndex(type); 
     ...
}

 function applyFilterValue(type, prop, value) {
     var index=filterIndex(type);
     ...
}
```

Let's say i add some filters `['Sharpen','Tint']` that are stored in the `canvas.filters` object as usual, and after canvas save/load are repositioned.
Then when i want to display the filter edit box for a image layer i execute this:

```
var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
filterNames = [];
obj.filters.forEach(function(f,i){
    filterNames.push(f.type);
});
for (var i=0;i<filterNamesDefault.length;i++){
    if (!filterNames.includes(filterNamesDefault[i])) filterNames.push(filterNamesDefault[i]);
}
```

Now the new order for `filterNames` is:

```
['Sharpen', 'Tint', 'Contrast', 'Saturation', 'invert', 'grayscale', 'Sepia']
```

And it works as well with the new order of the filters.